# syntax error(missing operator) in query expression when using delphi and ms access

Tags: delphi, ms-access

Does anyone know the source of this error:

> project xxxx.exe raised exception class EoleException with message
>   'syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'serial number=?'

this is my actual code in delphi with ms access database.

```
with AddIndividualsAccountADOQuery do
begin
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Add('Select * from IndividualAccount where Serial Number=:Sno');
  Parameters.ParamByName('Sno').Value:=edit1.Text;
  Open;
  Active:= True;
end;
```

the actual code runs well with delphi and sql database. but when i use ms access, the above error results when i run the application.

Answer (score 7):

I believe with MS-Access you need brackets around the name (since it contains a space):

```
Select * from IndividualAccount where [Serial Number]=:Sno
```